# JQuery Capitalize First Letter Of Each Word In A Sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to capitalize first letter of each word from a text field using JQuery but unfortunately I'm unable to.

Below is the Bootstrap code I currently have to get data from a text field from a submitted button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn4" value="alternatingCase">Alternating Case</button>
```

Below JQuery code converts only the first letter of the paragraph to caps

```
$("#btn4").click(function(){
  var input = $("#input1");
  input.val(input.val().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.val().substr(1).toLowerCase());
  });
```

Comment: it is working as expected. What is the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to capitalize each word.

```js
$("#btn4").click(function() {
  // create an array by splitting the value
  let input = $("#input1").val().split(' ').map((item) => {
   // take each word & capitalize the first word and return the word
   return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  })
   // use join to create a string from array values
  $("#input1").val(input.join(' '))


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input1">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn4" value="alternatingCase">Alternating Case</button>
```